# The query results obtained using elasticsearchOperation differ from those obtained using curl

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am currently attempting to query certain indexes using `spring-data-elasticsearch`'s `elasticSearchOperations`, employing the following query:

```kotlin
        val index = IndexCoordinates.of("test-*-en")

        val searchQuery = NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withFilter(
                QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("english","test query : 12345678"))
            ).withMaxResults(30)
            .build()

        return elasticsearchOperations.search(searchQuery, TestEsDocument::class.java, index)
```

However, I've observed a discrepancy in the query results obtained compared to those obtained via curl, despite employing the exact same query. I suspect this variance arises because the document with a higher score wasn't prioritized during the search when utilizing esSearchOperations.

I've included the curl query for reference:

```json
POST test-*-en/_search?size=30
{
  "query": 
    {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "match" : {
          "english" : {
            "query" : "test query : 12345678",
            "operator" : "OR",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
}
```

Though uncertain, I suspect that the issue may lie in elasticsearchOperation not accurately reading the scores from elasticSearch, as shown in the provided screenshots.
[image: elasticSearchOperation's SearchResult]

Unfortunately, I am constrained to using es version `7.10.1-oss` and cannot upgrade so I am using `spring-data-elasticsearch:4.2.12`, internally setting `elasticsearch.version` to `7.10.1` using the following options:

```
extra["elasticsearch.version"] = "7.10.1"
```

Could you advise if this issue arises from the version mismatch between `spring-data-elasticsearch` and my Elasticsearch cluster, and whether it's possible to resolve this issue? Alternatively, should I consider altering my query request to utilize a custom-built WebClient Post request instead?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data Elasticsearch returns 30 of the top scored results (the max score is 1.0) and you get 30 of them, you did not specify a sort order. The ones returned by curl, do they have the same score?

Edit:

I just saw that in your java code you add the query as a filter. So you will first get the result of getting all data without any scoring and then pass them through the filter. Add the query as query and not as filter.

Comment: Sadly, no. When I use curl to send the identical query as I did with elasticSearchOperations, the maximum score achieved is 9.662176, with each search result exhibiting varying scores such as 9.662176, 6.743596, 6.743596, and so forth.

Comment: Apologies for my mistake, and thank you very much! It works properly now.